# Volume of $x^2+y^2 \leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (solution check)

Tags: integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the volume $V$ of the solid $W = \lbrace (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2 \leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \rbrace$. I plot the region with Desmos 3D. After a change to cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta , z)$, I put
$$ V = \iiint_ W 1 \ dxdydz =\int _{\theta = 0} ^{2\pi} \int _{r = 0} ^1 \int_{z=r^2 }^r r \ dzdrd\theta $$
I don't care about the solution, just if I put the limits of the integrals correct. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical coordinates you have:
$$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos \vartheta \\
y=r\sin \vartheta\\
z=z
\end{cases} $$
and the Jacobian is $r$.
Your domain $W$ becomes:

$$\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2=r^2\le z\\
z\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r
\end{cases} $$
Moreover, $\vartheta \in[0,2\pi]$ and $0\le r\le1$; hence the integral is:
$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{r^2}^r r\,\, \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\vartheta $$